# Association mapping in Doctrine

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I have 2 tables: `jobs` and `categories`. The first table has a field called `cat_id` which is a reference to `categories`.`id`. In my Entity Class `Job` I have annotations like this:

```
 /**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
 * @JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $category;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->category = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

And in my Category Class I have:

```
/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Job", mappedBy="job")
* @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="cat_id")
*/
private $jobs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->jobs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

All I want is to get all jobs with their categories and all jobs by category. But I'm still new to Doctrine.

Comment: Your Entity is correct here, no ? I guess you should create your custom request by using the query builder in your EntityRepository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be overlooking some elements of the *owning* vs the *inverse* side of Doctrine relationship mappings. I suggest you read [12. Association Updates: Owning Side and Inverse Side](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) in the Doctrine manual for more details.

Essentially, one side of a 1:N relationship will be the *Owning* side, and the other the *Inverse* side. The owning side is the one that actually maps the relationship, while the inverse side simply reflects that mapping. - In your code, you've put the `JoinColumn` on both sides, as if both are supposed to be the owning side.

Your code should have the `Job.category` property as the owning side, and the `Category.jobs` property as the inverse side. So start by changing the Job entity to look more like this:

```
/**
 * @var Category
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="jobs")
 * @JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $category;

public function __construct()
{
    // $category would be a single instance of Category,
    // not a collection. Otherwise you'd be looking at a
    // ManyToMany relationship.
}
```

And then change the Category entity to look like this:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Job", mappedBy="category")
 */
private $jobs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->jobs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Note that in the Job entity, I've added the `inversedBy` attribute to the `ManyToOne` annotation, indicating the `Category.jobs` property as the inverse side of the mapping. Then I've removed the `JoinColumn` from the `Category.jobs` attribute, since the inverse side shouldn't actually specify a mapping directly; it is reflects the mapping of the owning side.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went through the documentation several times, trying to figure out what is `owning` or `inverse` side mean. Now everything works as I wanted. :)